# Problems understanding the workings behind C++ Algorithm Binary Search

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, binary-search

I was looking through the list of [algorithms](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) and decided to have a look at the [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) method

**Find Method**

```
template<class InputIterator, class T>
  InputIterator find (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val)
{
  while (first!=last) {
    if (*first==val) return first;
    ++first;
  }
  return last;
}
```

It seems **Find** has a running time of Big O (n) as it iterates through every element in the container to find the value.

My thoughts immediately thought of [Binary Search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/) and I went to have a look at it .

**Binary Search**

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
  bool binary_search (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& val)
{
  first = std::lower_bound(first,last,val);
  return (first!=last && !(val<*first));
}
```

Knowing that it utilises another function : [lower bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) , I went on to research lower bound which **returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first,last) which does not compare less than val.**

**This is my analysis**

Assuming an array data structure

[ 1 , 4 , 7 , 10 , 12 ]

If we use binary search to search for 6 , `first` would be equal to an iterator pointing to 7

`*first` would be of value 1 , `val` would be of value 6 then 
`!(val<*first)` would be true

Since `first!=last` == true && `!(val<*first)` == true 
, the binary search function would return true even though 6 does not exist in the array

> I know there is flaw in my reasoning , can someone explain to me where
>   did i go wrong ???

Comment: If `first` is an iterator pointing to 7, then it seems unlikely that `*first` would be of value 1...

Comment: `first would be equal to an iterator pointing to 7` and `*first would be of value ` are incompatible statements. Pick one you think is true and continue from there.

Comment: assuming I looked for 7 instead of 6 , *first would be 10  hence !(val<*first) would be false  and binary search would return false though 7 exist in the array , whats wrong with this reasoning

Comment: No, if you looked for 7 `*first` would be 7, because 7 is the first element not less than 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `*first` would be of value 1

There's your problem. `first` is an iterator to the element with value 7, so `*first` is 7. That makes `!(val<*first)` become `!(6<7)` which is `false`.

Comment: assuming I looked for 7 instead of 6 , *first would be 10 hence !(val<*first) would be false and binary search would return false though 7 exist in the array , whats wrong with this reasoning –  Computernerd 8 mins ago

Comment: @Computernerd That's not true. `lower_bound` finds the first value that is *not lower* than the value you're looking for. So it would find `7`.

Comment: The issue is that to actually *find* the value (as opposed to bounding it), the function would have to take a less-than comparison operator *and* an equality-comparison operator. The design philosophy of the STL is genericity and performance. There is no performance cost to using `lower_bound` and then testing for equality in your own function. Some things are not equality comparable.